# angular display model on view after getting data from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am working on displaying collection that I got from DB in angular with firebase DB. I have those controller and service setup. in the html, I use search.users expecting it will hold all the data that I got from the DB but it won't show up. I can't figure out why. I tried few things like angular.copy or $broadcast with no luck. Can anyone help advise on this? Appreciated in advance.

```
  .controller('SearchController', function ($scope, SearchService, logout, $location){

  var search = this;

  search.users = SearchService.users; 

  //$scope.$on('evtputUsers', function () {
  //  search.users = SearchService.users;
  //});

})

//service for SearchService
.factory('SearchService', function ($http, $rootScope){

  var userRef = new Firebase("app url");

  var broadcastUsers = function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('evtputUsers');
  };

  //get the user info
  //insert the data to the db.
  //retrieving the data

  var dbUsers;
  userRef.child('users').on('value', function(snapshot){
    dbUsers = snapshot.val();
    // angular.copy(snapshot.val(), dbUsers); 
    console.log('usersinDB:',dbUsers);
    broadcastUsers();
  }, function(err){
    console.error('an error occured>>>', err);
  });

  return {
    users: dbUsers
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `$broadcast()` and `$on()` you should use the [`AngularFire`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) module.

AngularFire provides you with a set of bindings to synchronizing data in Angular.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase']) // 1
  .controller('SearchCtrl', SearchCtrl);

function SearchCtrl($scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var userRef = new Firebase("app url")
  $scope.users = $firebaseArray(userRef); // 2
  console.log($scope.users.length); // 3
}
```

There are three important things to take note of:

1. You need to include AngularFire as `firebase` in the dependency array.
2. The `$firebaseArray()` function will automagically synchronize your user ref data into an array. When the array is updated remotely it will trigger the `$digest()` loop for you and keep the page refreshed.
3. This array is asynchronous. It won't log anything until data has populated it. So if you're logs don't show anything initially, this is because the data is still downloading over the network.